# Neatly printing a .txt file in python

Tags: python, file, flask, text, pretty-print

I have a .txt file with text like the following:

```
Project Gutenberg Australia
a treasure-trove of literature
treasure found hidden with no evidence of ownership
```

but whenever I try to read this file in Python (using Flask - I'm uploading the file to a site), using the following lines:

```py
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
        f.stream.seek(0)
        content = f.read()
    return render_template("book.html", text=content)
```

My "book.html" file is like the following:

```
<pre>
{{ text }}
</pre>
```

I get something like the following:

```
b'\xef\xbb\xbf\r\nProject Gutenberg Australia\r\na treasure-trove of literature\r\ntreasure found hidden with no evidence of ownership\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\...]
```

How can I fix this so that what is displayed on my site is just like what is displayed in the .txt file? Do I need to modify "book.html" or just read the file differently with Python?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `spltlines`? Just pass the result of `f.read()`.

Comment: Just as an FYI, `\xEF\xBB\xBF` is a UTF-8 [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding)

Comment: f.read() just makes it worse, like this: `b'\xef\xbb\xbf\r\nProject Gutenberg Australia\r\na treasure-trove of literature\r\ntreasure found hidden with no evidence of ownership\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `.decode()` your bytes:

```
print(b'\xef\xbb\xbf\r\nProject Gutenberg Australia\r\na treasure-trove of literature\r\ntreasure found hidden with no evidence of ownership\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\...]'.decode())
```

gives:

```
Project Gutenberg Australia
a treasure-trove of literature
treasure found hidden with no evidence of ownership



\...]
```